# store preferences in google chrome extentions

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

Using firefox, I can store extension preferences using `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);`

What interface can I use to store preferences in Chrome? And do they get overwritten on an extension update?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the localStorage API.  See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html for an example of building an options page with this, but most simply you can do:

```
localStorage['foo'] = 'bar';   // Store data
var foo = localStorage['foo']; // Get data
```

This data won't be wiped out on extension update, either.

Comment: In fact, `localStorage` is preserved even if the user uninstalls the extension, then installs it again. However, in Chrome 4 clearing browser data/cache will wipe it out.

Answer (score 1):

The new HTML5 feature to persist data locally (localStorage) should help you here.

In addition to coockies, now there are session and local storage objects, as well as, a simple version of relational database (all storing data on your local harddisk).

One hint when storing/retrieving objects to localStorage ... it is a simple implementation of the Map interface, so the safest way to persist your object is by serializing them via JSON.stringify function and parse retrieved string with JSON.parse.